# QT5. How QNetworkAccessManager writes data to QTcpSocket when makes HTTP request?

Tags: c++, qt, http, qt5

QT5. How `QNetworkAccessManager` writes data to `QTcpSocket` when makes `HTTP request`?

I investigate C++ QT5 source codes, and I can't understand how it works.
I mean, chain of classes from QNetworkAccessManager class to QTcpSocket.
I want to understand full path from QNetworkAccessManager class to QTcpSocket with all intermediate classes, and to understand how these classes (and which method) refer to each other

Comment: Google for Peter Hartmann's blog posts on the matter.

Comment: You're making it way harder for yourself than it needs to be. Prepare a debug build of Qt, run any of the network-manager-based examples under the debugger. You can then easily trace into Qt code and see what's happening. Ensure that you add breakpoints on relevant slots, since the code is asynchronous - it'll be evident which ones once you follow the code as it runs, not on paper.